# Windows Batch - Find all pdf's in sub directories, exclude specific foldernames

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, nested

**Context**

I'm currently programming with batch files, to use a specific pdf tool only available for cmd.

**Problem**

I'm trying to run a for loop, which recursively cycles through a directory finding all *.pdf files. Excluding the pdf's inside folders named "Originals"

If the pdf file is in a parent folder named "Originals", then it must be skipped. Otherwise count the pdf file with the %counter% variable.

**Example Directory Structure**

```
C:\New folder\file (1).pdf
C:\New folder\file (2).pdf

C:\New folder\Sub_1\file (1).pdf
C:\New folder\Sub_1\file (2).pdf
C:\New folder\Sub_1\file (3).pdf

C:\New folder\Sub_2\file (4).pdf
C:\New folder\Sub_2\file (5).pdf

C:\New folder\Originals\file (1).pdf
C:\New folder\Originals\file (2).pdf
```

**Example batch file - Find all pdf's (excluding Originals)**

```
:: Example.bat
@echo off

set myDirectory=C:\New folder
:: Search through myDirectory to find all .pdf files (including subdirectories)

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /R "%myDirectory%" %%G in (*.pdf) do (
    set inputDirectory=%%~dpG
    echo G              = !%%G!
    echo inputDirectory = !inputDirectory!

    for /f "delims=\" %%F in ("!inputDirectory!") do (
        set currentFolder=%%~nxF
        echo currentFolder = !currentFolder!
    )

    if NOT "!currentFolder!"=="Originals" (
        set /a count=count+1
    )
)
echo There are %count% PDF's (excluding originals)
pause
```

Please run the example batch file to demonstrate what I have so far. Any help or solutions would be appreciated.

Cheers!

**Solved**

Here's what I came up with based on everyone's solutions!

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set count=0
set myDirectory=C:\New folder

for /r "%myDirectory%" %%i in (*.pdf) do (
    set inputDirectory=%%~dpi
    set inputDirectoryNoSlash=!inputDirectory:~0,-1!
    for %%j in (!inputDirectoryNoSlash!) do set sub=%%~nxj
    if NOT !sub!==Originals (
        set /a count=count+1
    )
)

echo There are %count% PDF's (excluding originals)
pause
```

Thanks again guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another similar method is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set count=0
set dir=C:\TEST
echo %count%

for /r "%dir%" %%i in (*.pdf) do (
    set dirx=%%~dpi
    set con=!dirx:~0,-1!
    for %%j in (!con!) do set sub=%%~nxj
    if !sub!==Originals (
    cls
    ) else (
    set /a count=count+1
    )
    )
echo !count!
pause
```

*Change to appropriate pathname

Answer (score 1):

`%%~pG` Expand `%%G` to a Path only *including* a trailing `\` backslash. Undesired, clear it away as follows:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=\" %%F in ("!inputDirectory:~0,-1!") do (
    set currentFolder=%%~nxF
    echo currentFolder = !currentFolder!
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set myDirectory=C:\New folder
set count=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /S "%myDirectory%\*.pdf" ^| findstr /V /L "\Originals\"') do (
   echo File: %%a
   set /A count+=1
)
echo There are %count% PDF's (excluding originals)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort Aacini, but unfortunately I couldn't get this to work properly, that example gives me the wrong file count. Interesting method though.